DNS Resolution Issue on Free Hotspot via mobile router: "No address associated with hostname"
I am using an Ubuntu machine connected through a GL.iNet router to access a free hotspot, but I am facing DNS resolution issues. When I try to access the hotspot login page, I get the following error:

Error resolving “wifi.sncf”: No address associated with hostname

Here are the network details:
IP address: XX.XX.X.XXX
Netmask: 255.255.248.0
Gateway: 10.20.0.2
DNS Server: 10.20.0.2

Steps I've taken:

Verified and manually set DNS to Google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) on the Ubuntu machine. I don't know if and how to do it on the GL.iNet interface
Restarted the Network Manager on the Ubuntu machine.

However, I still receive the same error. When testing DNS resolution with nslookup and dig, the results are as follows:
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/Desktop$ nslookup wifi.sncf
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find wifi.sncf: No answer

(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/Desktop$ dig wifi.sncf

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> wifi.sncf
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58279
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wifi.sncf.         IN  A

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 15:09:22 CEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38

What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it? Is there something I'm missing in the DNS configuration or any other troubleshooting steps I should take, considering I'm using the GL.iNet router?
